# Determine expected winnings if a game is played where a fair coin is tossed until the first tail occurs

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

A game is played where a fair coin is tossed until the first tail occurs. The probability $x$ tosses will be needed is $f(x) = 0.5^x$, $x = 1,2,3,\dots\;$. You win $2^x$ if $x$ tosses are needed for $x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ but lose $256$ if $x > 5$. Determine your expected winnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Your expected winnings are just the weighted sum of your possible winnings, the weight of a given winning being the probability of that winning. You have:

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
\text{tosses}&\text{winnings}&\text{probability}&\text{weighted winnings}\\ \hline
1&2&\frac12&1\\
2&4&\frac14&1\\
3&8&\frac18&1\\
4&16&\frac1{16}&1\\
5&32&\frac1{32}&1\\ \hline
6&-256&\frac1{64}&?\\
7&-256&\frac1{128}&?\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots
\end{array}$$

The weighted sum of the first five rows is $5$. Set up an infinite series for the weighted sum of the rest, evaluate it, and add to $5$ to get the expected winnings.

Comment: i do not know how to find P(x>5)(-256)

Comment: @Harold: For $x>5$ that’s just $$-256\left(\frac12\right)^x=-\frac{256}{2^x}=-\frac{2^8}{2^x}=-2^{8-x}\;.$$

Comment: wait, i think i have it, is P(x>5)(-256)=(−256)(0.5)^5 = -8, then I need to add 5, so answer is -3?

Comment: @Harold: Yes, that looks good: $$5-256\sum_{n\ge 6}\left(\frac12\right)^n=5-\frac{256}{32}=5-8=-3\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $X$ denote the random variable that indicates the number of tosses the game goes.

Your expected winnings are $$Pr(X=1)2^1+Pr(X=2)2^2+Pr(X=3)2^3+Pr(X=4)2^4+Pr(X=5)2^5+Pr(X>5)(-256)$$

To find $Pr(X>5)$, use the fact that $Pr(X>5)=1-Pr(X=1)-Pr(X=2)-Pr(X=2)-Pr(X=3)-Pr(X=4)-Pr(X=5)$.

Comment: well probability of P(X=1)2+P(X=2)4+P(X=3)8+P(X=4)16+P(X=5)32 = 1+1+1+1+1 =5 but i have no clue how to find P(x>5)(-256)

Comment: wait, i think i have it, is P(x>5)(-256)=(−256)(0.5)^5 = -8, then I need to add 5, so answer is -3?